# Number with icon from right middle

Tags: html, css

I have a number and I want to put a star icon next to it, but in the middle.

The font-size of the number can be changed, but the star should stay in the middle.

For examples:

[image]

This is my css:

```
.my-container {
    display: inline-block;
}

.my-text {
    font-family: "Courier-new";
    font-size:20px
}

.my-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```css
.my-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.my-text {
  font-family: "Courier-new";
  font-size: 20px
}

.my-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="my-container">
  <span class="my-text">5</span>
  <span class='icon icon-star my-icon'></span>
</div>
```

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k48ttuLn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use flexbox for this. It will vertically center the content no matter the size.

```css
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.my-text {
  font-family: "Courier-new";
  font-size: 20px
}

.my-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <span class="my-text">5</span>
  <span class='icon icon-star my-icon'></span>
</div>
```

See [A guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more examples and tutorials

Answer (score 2):

```
.my-text {
    font-family: "Courier-new";
    font-size:20px
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used a combination of `line-height` and `vertical-align: middle` to achieve this:

```css
* {
  line-height: 1;
}

.my-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-text {
  font-family: "Courier-new";
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 0.2;
}

.big-font .my-text {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="my-container">
  <span class="my-text">5</span>
  <span class='icon icon-star my-icon'></span>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="my-container big-font">
  <span class="my-text">15</span>
  <span class='icon icon-star my-icon'></span>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hn6ekzo5/**